# Splitting string in javascript using RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to use `RegEx` to split the following string:

```
"C=US,ST=NY,O=GOOGLE\, INC"
```

The intention is for `O=GOOGLE\, INC` to stay intact after splitting on comma.

Comment: What about `\\,` does that stay intact?

Comment: Maybe just split using regex `(?<!\\),`

Comment: The idea is to not split on commas that that are preceded by '\' or '\\' characters.

Comment: If you don't care about odd/even `\\`, use that regex in split.

Comment: Yea that works.I was not aware of '<!' as an option. What does that do?

Comment: Its a look behind assertion. Says as long as the comma is not preceded by a back slash.

Comment: Javascript does not support look-behind.

Comment: The tag wasn't there before. But, see it in title now.

Comment: Crap, I was testing it within Java and it worked. Applying it within javascript code, does not. Any workaround for this using RegEx?

Comment: Don't use split, just match all with a regex.

Comment: Might be easier to just write this in pure JS. Loop, break the string apart when you find a `,`, except when preceded by a \. Not too difficult.

Comment: Yea I agree with that. Will write a function that does this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data looks like it will be fairly reliably of the form:

foo=bar,spic=span,a=bob\,fred

ie, pairs of key=val data, with escaped commas in the data. So if the escaped commas are *only* in the data, then you can use a simple lookahead for the 'key=' as part of your regexp. Assuming the key is always in capitals, then this works:

```
s = "C=US,ST=NY,O=GOOGLE\, INC"
s.split(/,(?=[A-Z]*=)/)
```

ie, split on a comma if it is followed by some capitals and an equals.

This will give you

```
["C=US", "ST=NY", "O=GOOGLE, INC"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can do without split, you can just use a regex like this that captures field data.
*edit* - Modified to match spurious escapes as well.

```
 #  /(?:^|,)((?:[^,\\]*(?:\\,|\\)?)+)(?:(?=,)|$)/

 (?: ^ | , )            # Leading comma or BOL
 (                      # (1 start), Field data
      (?:
           [^,\\]* 
           (?: \\, | \\ )?
      )+
 )                      # (1 end)
 (?:                    # Lookahead, comma or EOL
      (?= , )
   |  $ 
 )
```

Output >>

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 0 , len 4 ) 
C=US  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 0 , len 4 ) 
C=US  

--------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 4 , len 6 ) 
,ST=NY  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 5 , len 5 ) 
ST=NY  

--------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 10 , len 15 ) 
,O=GOOGLE\, INC  
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 11 , len 14 ) 
O=GOOGLE\, INC
```